# Problem installing mcrypt on PHP 7.3.13 Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, mcrypt

This is what I have been doing.

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
$ sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-de
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2
> libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] :
```

Im adding "extension=mcrypt.so" to php.ini

Then I do

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
```

I followed these instruction: https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/

Lastly I check with `php -i | grep mcrypt`

This is my output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini
```

I have checked both 20-mcrypt.ini and mcrypt.ini and they look exaclty the same. 
But my PHP seems to be compiled with the wrong module API. I google around but couldn't find anything specific on that. Any idéas? Thanks!

[image]

What I have been using

- https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
- [Issue in installing php7.2-mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt)
- https://gist.github.com/arzzen/1209aa4a430bd95db3090a3399e6c35f
- [Howto ubuntu 18.04 install / activate PHP extension ext-mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354696/howto-ubuntu-18-04-install-activate-php-extension-ext-mcrypt)

Comment: First of all I would try to install mcrypt 1.0.3 because it's latest stable now. Also are there other folders under `/usr/lib/php/`?

Comment: Alright. Yes 20131226  20151012  20160303  20170718  20180731  20190902  7.0  7.1  7.3  7.4  php-helper  php-maintscript-helper  sessionclean. Any clue?

Comment: does the compiled module go only into "20190902"? maybe it's in "20180731" also?

Comment: Yes it seems like that. the mcrypt.so is in both 2018 and 2019. Should I delete the one in 2018?

Comment: Probably you can try using extension from `extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/mcrypt.so` instead of `extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so`

Comment: I changed the 20-mcrypt.ini and mcrypt.ini to 20180731 and I restarted the server. But I stil got the same error :O

Answer (score 10):

I've found the solution to same problem.

In my case `pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2` diplays something like

```
...
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] :
```

and problem persists also specifyng `20180731` in `autodetect`.

After some checks I've figured out the problem: php cli runs php 7.3 so I thought that was well configured, but both `phpize` and `php-config` are linked to php 7.4!

So you just have to launch the follows:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.3
```

and reistalled a newest version

```
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2
```

That's all.

> Note:
>
> 1. eventually run `pecl uninstall mcrypt` before install the right version
> 2. if you don't find `phpize7.3` and `php-config7.3`, try installing via `apt-get install php7.3-dev`

Comment: Finally a good solution, I've been digging with this for weeks! Thanks!

Comment: i have been looking for this solution for the past couple of days. thanks @Sim Sca

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been using pecl command to install mcrypt for PHP7.4, however, it used to give me errors on Homestead telling me build numbers are different since it defaults with PHP8. Update-alternatives commands were the life saver for me. Thanks!